# Получить версию приложения Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

Пытаюсь получить версию приложения функцией, которая находится в dll:

```
{ 8. Получить версию приложения }
function GetVersion: string;
type
  TVerInfo = packed record
    Arr: array [0 .. 47] of byte; // ненужные нам 48 байт
    Minor, Major, Build, Release: word; // а тут версия
  end;
var
  s: TResourceStream;
  v: TVerInfo;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    s := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, '#1', RT_VERSION); // достаём ресурс
    if s.Size > 0 then
    begin
      s.Read(v, SizeOf(v)); // читаем нужные нам байты
      Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [v.Major, v.Minor, v.Release, v.Build]);
    end;
    freeandnil(s);
  except
    On e: EReadError do
      messageDlg(e.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

Собственно в приложении связываю так:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function GetVersion: string; external 'collfnc.dll'; // 8. Получить версию приложения
```

Вызов:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GetVersion);
end;
```

Но в результате получаю версию не приложения, а dll

Comment: HInstance - это хендл на "себя". Если код в длл - то, соответственно, ссылка идет на dll

Comment: Как в таком случае мне поступить, не подскажете?

Comment: Вам нужна функция GetFileVersionInfo. Но это надо оформить ответом, т.к. комментарии - это всего лишь комментарии. Если кто (например Вы) оформите как ответ с приложением кода (он очень прост) - будет просто замечательно!

Comment: Дополнение: функции, экспортируемые из dll, не должны использовать string. Ни в явном ни в косвенном виде (к примеру - в составе record-ов или классов. Особенно - классов. Сами классы тоже). Никогда. В качестве костыля - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Sharing_Memory . И комментарий в dpr при создании dll вас об этом предупреждал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение:

```
function GetVersion(filename:String): string;
 var
   VerInfoSize: DWORD;
   VerInfo: Pointer;
   VerValueSize: DWORD;
   VerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
   Dummy: DWORD;
 begin
   VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(filename), Dummy);
   GetMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
   GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(filename), 0, VerInfoSize, VerInfo);
   VerQueryValue(VerInfo, '\', Pointer(VerValue), VerValueSize);
   with VerValue^ do
   begin
     Result := IntToStr(dwFileVersionMS shr 16);
     Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionMS and $FFFF);
     Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionLS shr 16);
     Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionLS and $FFFF);
   end;
   FreeMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
end;
```

Вызов:

```
GetVersion(paramstr(0))
```

Comment: В вызове достаточно будет просто GetVersion(ParamStr(0))

Comment: @kami Действительно. Вы правы

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetAppVersionStr: string;
var
  Exe: string;
  Size, Handle: DWORD;
  Buffer: TBytes;
  FixedPtr: PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
  Exe := ParamStr(0);
  Size := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(Exe), Handle);
  if Size = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  SetLength(Buffer, Size);
  if not GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(Exe), Handle, Size, Buffer) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if not VerQueryValue(Buffer, '\', Pointer(FixedPtr), Size) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  // major
  Result := Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [LongRec(FixedPtr.dwFileVersionMS).Hi,
    LongRec(FixedPtr.dwFileVersionMS).Lo, // minor
    LongRec(FixedPtr.dwFileVersionLS).Hi, // release
    LongRec(FixedPtr.dwFileVersionLS).Lo]) // build
end;
```